# Android,how to get time of record in Samsung health?

Tags: android

I integrate Samsung health into my application. I can able to read, write data. I have set up an observer so when ever there is a change Samsung health it will notify my app. My problem is I cannot find it's date. I have tried with for example `health constant.Weight.CREATE_TIME` and `health constant.Weight.UPDATE_TIME` but it gives me the time of insertion. When entering manually I have changed the date to FRI, 19 JAN 2018, 16:33 and inserted at MON, 22 January 2018 10:41:39. How can I get FRI, 19 JAN 2018, 16:33 instead of Monday, 22 January 2018 10:41:39? What is the correct constant? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use START_TIME it will be default for all category.

Comment: you mean START_TIME

Comment: Sorry START_TIME

Comment: Thank you. You saved a day.